# What information could be recovered from visualized magnetic information?

Tags: floppy-disk, storage, magnetic-tape

I was wondering how the data on a floppy disk physically looks like. With data stored on a magnetic disk obviously that isn't visible. The [Wikipedia article on floppy disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk) however shows a beautiful visualization of the magnetic information on floppy disk recorded with CMOS-MagView, a high-resolution and precise measuring and visualization system for magnetic materials.

Below visualization is obviously not a full disk scan but considering we had a full disk scanned and visualized in that format: *What information could be extracted from visualized magnetic information? Could it be visualization be decoded into data? What does it tell us about the quality of the material? Could we tell what formatting type was used on this floppy disk? Are the vertical stripes the separation of tracks and the horizontal thin stripes sectors? Or are we looking at (a part of) one sector or cluster?*

Lastly, has CMOS-MagView or a similar system ever been used as a (non-intrusive) data recovery method?

[image: CMOS-MagView visualization of magnetic information on floppy disk]

Comment: That's not a "stretched/flat visualization", those tracks are curved, but since it is zoomed in so much it is hard to see. Now I understand how flat-earthers get their start.

Comment: @GlenYates I cannot stop laughing about your flat-earthers comment. :') Although I have luckily never been associated with that. But, I agree that some sub questions need rephrasing or removal. I will edit the question.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I didn't mean to imply that you were a flat-earther, just that it is their inability to realize just how big the earth really is and how 'zoomed in' we are, making local phenomena appear flat, thus leading to their belief.

Comment: What we see here are most likely the sector headers.

Comment: It took 160ish years to decode and playback the first phonautographs (made circa 1860) and those were visual representations of audio waves - so with sufficient scanning resolution, and a healthy dose of patience, I suspect any magnetic media could be fully decode-able from a visual scan.

Comment: I saw [this guy](https://ofersp.github.io/digital_needle/) scanned images of vinyl records round 20 years ago and converted them into digital audio files.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oona Räisänen/windytan posted a few articles on the topic.  See [see here](https://www.windytan.com/2013/02/the-atomic-powered-robot.html), [here](https://www.windytan.com/2013/02/the-laser-equipped-lego-train.html), and [here](https://www.windytan.com/2017/07/gramophone-audio-from-photograph.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What information could be extracted from visualized magnetic information?

The very same as with a magnetic head: flux changes - and from there everything else, like headers, sectors and the data within.

> Could below visualization be decoded into data?

It can be decoded into a bitstream, as it seems to hold one. But I doubt that the shown section is long enough to regain  useful information.

> What does it tell us about the quality of the material?

Nothing, it tells about magnetic flux changes. That is what magnetic properties are there *at the moment*.

> Could we tell what formatting type was used on this floppy disk?

As mentioned, it's the same information a head can read, thus the same information a format can be made of.

> Are the vertical stripes the separation of tracks

They are obvious the *gaps* between tracks (running to down) as there is no coherent magnetization but random domains.

> in a stretched/flat visualization

This seems not to be stretched in any way, but visibly curves, so it's tracks. Most likely of a hard disk platter, as for a floppy the gaps would be *way* broader in comparison to the track width. In addition fluxes on a floppy *may* have less sharp borders (for older drives at least)

> and the horizontal thin stripes sectors? Or are we looking at (a part of) one sector

They are magnetic changes in vertical succession. Keep in mind magnetic changes are not bits/bytes, but encoded bits/bytes. The colours and 'thickness' of stripes is not real, but a side effect of visualization and timing of magnetic fluxes. From the type of magnetic encoding that should be on a disk we can infer what it must look like:

- Sync data usually carries sequences with less changes to enable pickup of the clock, thus will look like wider stripes with more visible 'colour'
- Data in contrast is usually of random bit sequence encoded with the maximum number of changes get density, thus must be looking thinner and more equal.
- Headers are short data blocks
- Sectors are long data blocks.

Taking this, the shown part *may* cover the area two sectors and gap/synchronisation/header data inbetween. Rotational sequence seems to be bottom to top showing

- End of a sector (darker thin stripes)
- Sector gap with sync data (yellowish seemingly wider stripes)
- Header data (short sequence of dark/thin stripes)
- Header gap with sync data (yellowisch wider again)
- Next sector (again darker thin stripes)

> or cluster?

Clusters are no units of magnetic recording, they are *logical* structures used in storage management. Only sectors (ordered in tracks) can be found on a magnetic media

> Lastly, has CMOS-MagView or a similar system ever been used as a (non-intrusive) data recovery method?

I would guess so. Then again, it's a huge effort to reach something that can be done by simply using a drive to read the platter. Cost will be quite high. Even with destroyed drives recovery usually done by taking the platters out, careful cleaning and mounting them in a new drive to finally read what is hopefully left.

---

P.S.: In Ye Olde Days it was common to read tapes, but as well disks visually by applying magnetic fluid. The human brain works quite well to decode this - at least once trained to see the diffeence. Been there, done that_))

Comment: You're fast. Thanks. I just changed the question a little bit based on the comment.

Comment: @BobOrtiz Well, the question is quite simple and easy. More concerning, that it is not a question about retro computing, but magnetic storage basics. It should not be asked here.

Comment: Years ago I knew someone who worked in a lab at a then well-known hard drive manufacturer. They had a very flexible system in the lab to map out surfaces. One of their common things to throw on the machine for fun was the paper tickets from the local metro. It did not take them long to figure out the coding sequence (and know how to rewrite them for an arbitrary amount of credit). The city never responded to their outreach attempts, trying to encourage a bit of security on them.

Comment: @Raffzahn Two reasons I think it should be here: (1) the answer could be different for modern magnetic storage where everything is smaller; (2) the subject matter experts are here.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 No to a) The basic principle doesn't change. A Chihuahua is still a dog ... given, a bordercase, but still a dog :) And b) quite some here are as well kind of informed about the workings of railways, does that mean Railway questions are as well topical? I got a few ... like about weird Japanese rail car naming schemes :))

Comment: @Raffzahn About the railway control computer systems? Why not?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Of course not, but they use the same electricity as computers do, so same basic technology to talk about.